# GSOn error Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT when parsing JSON response

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I retrieve a JSON result from an API :

```
[{
"oid": "axd7wtlk6xd2fbwlc5wk",
"id": "aazzzza",
"name": "aazzaa",
"logo": {
"type": 0,
"data": "iVB.............5CYII="
},
"timestamp": 1438608571013,
"email": "contact@azzaa.net",
"modified": "test",
"url": "http://www.azzaa.net"
},
{
"oid": "quj3dzygfwygl5uxsbxk",
"name": "KZZZ",
"modified": "test",
"timestamp": 1438854099511,
"id": "kess"
},...]
```

but when I try to map to a customer object I get the error `Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT` :

```
    response = webService.RequestGet(url, header);

    result = null;
    try {
        result = new JSONArray(response);
        Utils.LogWarning(response);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Utils.LogError("Could not load json response", e);
    }

    Type customerType = new TypeToken<Collection<Customer>>() {
    }.getType();
    ArrayList<Customer> alCustomers = null;
    alCustomers = new Gson().fromJson(result.toString(), customerType);
```

Here is my `Customer` class :

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private String id = "";
    private String name = "";
    private String email = "";
    private String url = "";
    private String address = "";
    private String stamp = "";
    //private transient String logo = "";
    private long timestamp = 0L;
    private String modified = "";
    ...
```

}

I have been through a lot of answers regarding this problem that I have also for other types of objects, but I can't find a working solution.

Comment: In your `Customer` class, is `logo` field a String?

Comment: show your `customer` class

Comment: Please match your `Customer` class properties type with the type you have in JSON.

Comment: logo is a field String but I added the `transient` keyword as I will store the path and not the image

Comment: logo is of type object. convert your class property to object and then keep only path.

Answer (score 2):

Create a modal with the values of JSON result like

```
    public class Customer {
        private String oid;
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String timestamp;
        private String email;
        private String modified;
        private String url;

        public String getOid() {
            return oid;
        }

        public void setOid(String oid) {
            this.oid = oid;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }

        public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getModified() {
            return modified;
        }

        public void setModified(String modified) {
            this.modified = modified;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public Logo getLogo() {
            return logo;
        }

        public void setLogo(Logo logo) {
            this.logo = logo;
        }

        private Logo logo;
    }

    public class Logo {
        private int type;

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        private String data;
    }

  Gson gson = new Gson();
 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Customer>>(){}.getType();
List<Customer> customer= (List<Customer>) gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
```

Comment: if a property is present in a JSON response, it must be present in the model ?